# Generating different types of nodes in LuaTeX

Tags: luatex

I am writing a tool to show the details of LuaTeX nodes. For example, this document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{luatexbase}

\begin{luacode*}
-- my developing source code
require "luatex-node-to-table"
inspect = require"inspect"

function test_ntt(n,s)
  for n1 in node.traverse(n) do
    -- my function
    local t = luatex_node_to_table(n1)
    texio.write_nl(inspect(t))
  end
  return n
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback("pre_linebreak_filter", test_ntt, "test_ntt")

\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}

A-B

\end{document}
```

would have the following output

```
{
  attr = {
    [0] = 0,
    id = "attribute_list(40)"
  },
  box_left = {},
  box_left_width = 0,
  box_right = {},
  box_right_width = 0,
  dir = "TLT",
  id = "local_par(9)",
  next = { "<node    462 <    417 >    398 : hlist 3>" },
  pen_broken = 0,
  pen_inter = 0,
  prev = {},
  subtype = {}
}
{
  attr = {
    [0] = 0,
    id = "attribute_list(40)"
  },
  depth = "0.000000pt",
  dir = "TLT",
  glue_order = 0,
  glue_set = 0.0,
  glue_sign = "normal(0)",
  head = {},
  height = "0.000000pt",
  id = "hlist(0)",
  list = {},
  next = { "<node    417 <    398 >    500 : glyph 256>" },
  prev = { "<node    nil <    462 >    417 : local_par 0>" },
  shift = 0,
  subtype = "indent(3)",
  width = "15.000000pt"
}
{
  attr = {
    [0] = 0,
    id = "attribute_list(40)"
  },
  char = "'A'(65)",
  components = {},
  data = 0,
  depth = "0.000000pt",
  expansion_factor = 0,
  font = 26,
  height = "6.888748pt",
  id = "glyph(29)",
  lang = 0,
  left = 2,
  next = { "<node    398 <    500 >    475 : disc 2>" },
  prev = { "<node    462 <    417 >    398 : hlist 3>" },
  right = 3,
  subtype = "*unknown*(256)",
  uchyph = 1,
  width = "7.500000pt",
  xoffset = 0,
  yoffset = 0
}
{
  attr = {
    [0] = 0,
    id = "attribute_list(40)"
  },
  id = "disc(7)",
  next = { "<node    500 <    475 >    329 : glyph 256>" },
  penalty = 50,
  post = {},
  pre = {
    attr = {
      [0] = 0,
      id = "attribute_list(40)"
    },
    char = "'-'(45)",
    components = {},
    data = 0,
    depth = "0.000000pt",
    expansion_factor = 0,
    font = 26,
    height = "2.416656pt",
    id = "glyph(29)",
    lang = 0,
    left = 1,
    next = {},
    prev = {},
    right = 1,
    subtype = "*unknown*(256)",
    uchyph = 0,
    width = "3.333328pt",
    xoffset = 0,
    yoffset = 0
  },
  prev = { "<node    417 <    398 >    500 : glyph 256>" },
  replace = {
    attr = {
      [0] = 0,
      id = "attribute_list(40)"
    },
    char = "'-'(45)",
    components = {},
    data = 0,
    depth = "0.000000pt",
    expansion_factor = 0,
    font = 26,
    height = "2.416656pt",
    id = "glyph(29)",
    lang = 0,
    left = 2,
    next = {},
    prev = {},
    right = 3,
    subtype = "*unknown*(256)",
    uchyph = 1,
    width = "3.333328pt",
    xoffset = 0,
    yoffset = 0
  },
  subtype = "automatic(2)"
}
{
  attr = {
    [0] = 0,
    id = "attribute_list(40)"
  },
  char = "'B'(66)",
  components = {},
  data = 0,
  depth = "0.000000pt",
  expansion_factor = 0,
  font = 26,
  height = "6.888748pt",
  id = "glyph(29)",
  lang = 0,
  left = 2,
  next = { "<node    475 <    329 >    482 : penalty 2>" },
  prev = { "<node    398 <    500 >    475 : disc 2>" },
  right = 3,
  subtype = "*unknown*(256)",
  uchyph = 1,
  width = "7.082993pt",
  xoffset = 0,
  yoffset = 0
}
{
  attr = {
    [0] = 0,
    id = "attribute_list(40)"
  },
  id = "penalty(14)",
  next = { "<node    329 <    482 >    nil : glue 15>" },
  penalty = 10000,
  prev = { "<node    500 <    475 >    329 : glyph 256>" },
  subtype = "linepenalty(2)"
}
{
  attr = {
    [0] = 0,
    id = "attribute_list(40)"
  },
  id = "glue(12)",
  leader = {},
  next = {},
  prev = { "<node    475 <    329 >    482 : penalty 2>" },
  shrink = 0,
  shrink_over = {},
  stretch = 65536,
  stretch_over = {},
  subtype = "parfillskip(15)",
  width = "0.000000pt"
}
```

I would like to test if my code works for all LuaTeX nodes, especially `whatsit` nodes. Is there a way to create a document where all types of nodes are present?

One more side question, besides using `pre_linebreak_filter`, is there a way to traverse all nodes in a document?

Comment: Your final question is not clear. What do you mean exactly by "all" and "document" here? `pre_linebreak_ filter will include nodes not in the final document eg discarded nodes after a linebreak, or all the nodes in a vbox that is placed in a box register that isn't used (eg trial typesetting for balanced columns) conversely it will not show nodes that are in the final document that were not involved in linebreaking eg any nodes added directly to the main vertical list from \hbox or \vskip etc.

Comment: you don't (normally) need to load `luatexbase` that is a legacy package that defines a few extra functions for compatibility, the `luatexbase` table and callback methods are defined by default in latex. Also `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` usually not wanted in luatex, as it forces 8bit fonts.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am not familiar wit LuaTeX's fundamentals. By saying the entire document, I am assuming the entire document is represented in terms of nodes in the end, and I would like to acquire the root node.